# Domain privacy Vimeo on localhost

Tags: ios, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I have an iPhone app that take video links from Youtube/Vimeo/Brightcove. Everything works fine except when domain level privacy is used.

In Vimeo there is a field in Privacy that says 'Where can this video be embedded?'. If another company sends me a Vimeo link and uses these privacy settings on my website (http://www.example.com) then the Vimeo link does not work on my locally hosted iPhone app, and returns an error.

I have tried using 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' in the privacy settings but this does not work either.

Is there anyway I can get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Domain privacy does not currently have any mobile web-view workarounds.

Vimeo generally recommends users upgrade to a PRO account so you can access your video files directly through the API.